# rotating View after loading

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, rotation

In one of my applications I implemented a view that can play a movie. the oriantation of the view is Portrait. I overwrite the foloowing method so the view will rotate once the movie is playing.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (isPlayingMovie) {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ||
                interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
    } else {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }  
}
```

The problem is that the view will not automatically rotate. I figured that the view calles this method in the view controller only  while it's loading but how can i force him to call it again ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: not possible.

Long answer: Just return that you do portrait only and rotate the view yourself.

Get rotation notifications (put it in viewDidAppear or something):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(rotationChange:)                                                 
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:nil];
```

Then do the rotation in "rotationChange:" (example for a webview here):

```
- (void)rotationChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIDeviceOrientation o = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    CGFloat rotation;
    [self.webView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
    switch (o) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            rotation = 0;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            rotation = 180;
    ...
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:o animated:YES];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rotation * (M_PI / 180.0f));
    [self.webView setTransform:transform];
}
```

EDIT: Don't forget to disable the notifications if you don't need them (like in "viewDidDisappear:")

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code in this method

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
//required functionality

}
```

Cheers